# how can cache "NotFound" page in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a custom **NotFound page** in my project that every false URL redirect to it by this code:

> In startup.cs:
>
> ```
> app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/not-found");
> ```

I want to serve this static page by a `cache policy`. how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first install this nuget package:

[WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching/1.0.28?_src=template)

And then add these code in startup.cs:

```
services.AddOutputCaching(); //ConfigureServices()
```

and

```
app.UseOutputCaching();  //Configure()
```

At last, add **OutputCache** attribute to your notfound() action, then it's output will be cached:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 6000)] //cache 6000 seconds
    public IActionResult notfound()
    {
        return View(DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I search your way and it is **server-side cache** . I use it, but I need **Browser cache** too. so with more search I found out with below code in front of notfound() action, I can cache it in browser too : `[ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = '<Time>')]`.